# AppCompleteGenericCore > 1Gb of memory

Tags: mdriven

The monitoring of the Local MDrivenServer (cmd: AppCompleteGenericCore.exe -port=5050 -nohttps) shows that the process eats memory up to 1.2Gb regardless of the Model's size.
If I upload the simplest sample model with Class1 and Class2, no viewmodels, no serverside jobs -  AppCompleteGenericCore process memory starts from 60Mb (there is no model) and stabilized at the ~1.2Gb (sample model is uploaded).
Could you please advise is it normal behavior?
FYI, I've tried "System.GC.Server": false, "System.GC.Concurrent": false in the AppCompleteGenericCore.runtimeconfig.json - no results.

Thank you!

Comment: quite strange, seems that it depends on the model -  if I upload SampleModelForAssosiations using  MDrivenDesigner - AppCompleteGenericCore memory is OK. But when I uploaded my model from VS2019 - memory became >1,3 Gb... The difference between models is that mine doesn't have ASPNetIdentiry package. I've tried to add/remove this package to reproduce the issue - no results. But memory is ok now... Strange.. I've to understand what's wrong were in the model/MDrivenServer settings

Comment: 1. Create empty DB in SQLServer
2. Run "dotnet AppCompleteGenericCore.dll -port=5050 -nohttps"
3. Switch to the SQLServer using the wiki Use_SqlServer
4. AppCompleteGenericCore memory is about 100-140Mb, ServerMode=Normal
5. Change the MDrivenServer's ServerMode to Master (MDrivenServerSynk table). AppCompleteGenericCore memory usage is about 200Mb - OK.
5. Stop AppCompleteGenericCore, start it again. 2-3 minutes AppCompleteGenericCore loads CPU +25%, I/O +20Mb, Mem is growing till 1.3Gb. You can Start/Stop the AppCompleteGenericCore - the same 2-3 minutes and memory 1.3Gb at the end

Comment: Regardless of the ServerMode - any restart of the AppCompleteGenericCore with external DB increases the AppCompleteGenericCore memory usage >1Gb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my `LocalServers` folder and downloaded the latest version of `MDrivenServer`—and the problem disappeared. The old server had `CodeDress` assembly, so I guess it was a root cause of the memory leak I had.